# How assigning of variable works in Python?

Tags: python

I'm learning python. And below is my small code snippet. Language is DuckTyping, so now very less worry about `type`

Just want to know how this `["batman", "wonder woman", "flash"]` (dont know what's this, Array or tuple ?) assigned to `m` ?

```
class Team:
    def __init__(self, m):
        self.__members = m
        print(self.__members)
        print(m)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__members)

    def __contains__(self, m):
        return m in self.__members


justice_league_fav = Team(["batman", "wonder woman", "flash"])

# Sized protocol
print(len(justice_league_fav))
print(justice_league_fav)

# Container protocol
print("batman" in justice_league_fav)
print("superman" in justice_league_fav)
```

This seems to be a `__members` instance variable. That makes sense. Dont need to define like java. But how come `m` got assigned to `["batman", "wonder woman", "flash"]` ?

Any help ?

Comment: The  `__init__` is a constructor, so the affectation  is done here `self.__members = m`

Comment: Um, you *do* need to define a variable, or else you will get an `AttributeError` when you try to access it. It is defined right here: `self.__members = m` in `__init__`. As for `m`, it is a parameter to `__init__`, it got passed in here: `justice_league_fav = Team(["batman", "wonder woman", "flash"])`....

Comment: The list of names is passed to `Team.__init__` as the `m` argument when you use `Team(...)`. Is this what you are asking? I don't quite understand what you find unclear about this.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: self == this and __init__ is the constructor. And that isn't an array or a tuple, it's a list.

Comment: It's assigned implicitly the way function parameters always are. The only difference is that although the `m` argument is the first (and only) one, it gets assigned to the second argument (called `m`) because in Python instance methods the instance itself is always implicitly passed as the first argument (which by convention is always called `self`).

Comment: @azro, in constructor what's a significance of mentioning self ?

Comment: That is how python works, there is no `this` accessible all the time, the first parametre of an instance method is always the current instance, so mainly named `self`

Comment: @azro,  __init__ is not a instance method but a constructor only... Nope ?

Comment: @azro, I think that's just a syntax only..! :)

Comment: That a specifid one yes, but for `self` the explanation is the same

Comment: I'm still not understanding what you aren't understanding...

Answer (score 0):

First you call the constructor of `Team`:

```
justice_league_fav = Team(["batman", "wonder woman", "flash"])
```

Note that the `self` argument, the first argument, in the constructor is the `instance` of the class being created, so `m` is the ***actual*** sole parameter being passed.

Then the list `["batman", "wonder woman", "flash"]` is passed as the `m` argument (`m` is `["batman", "wonder woman", "flash"]`).

In `Team` constructor, the list is assigned to `__members` which is an instance variable.

```
self.__members = m
```

So when you print:

```
print(self.__members)
```

It's already initialized with the passed list.

Later on you print:

```
print(m)
```

This prints again the passed list argument.